# Mono add in many trusted certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, mono

I thought SSL on mono didnt work since it always reported a decode error. Now i realize by default mono doesnt trust anyone.

How do i add many trusted certificates? I seen this page which explains how to [add a certificate into mono using gmail as the example](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Security) but that is just one. How do i add many at once or maybe add everything that is in firefox or internet explorer since they trust a good amount of sites by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some reason you can't use the onpage suggestion of:

> Use the mozroots.exe tool (included in
>   Mono 1.1.10 and later) to download and
>   install all Mozilla's root
>   certificates (i.e. the ones used in
>   FireFox and other Mozilla's
>   softwares). It's easier than finding a
>   specific root but it's also less
>   granular to make a decision about
>   which one(s) you install or not.

Cause that would seem to be exactly what you want?

Comment: I didnt notice that. Also i was looking for a specific command. I found it `mozroots --import --sync`.